# Dynamically create asp:TextBox that accepts only Numbers

Tags: asp.net

I would like to know if it's possible to create asp.net TextBox from code behind that accepts only numbers. Is there any attribute I can Use?

I have this but If I put "a" it's Ok...

```
HtmlGenericControl divQta = (HtmlGenericControl)e.Row.FindControl("divQta");
TextBox txtQta = new TextBox();
txtQta.Attributes["type"] = "number";
txtQta.Text = dt.Rows[e.Row.RowIndex][2].ToString();
divQta.Controls.Add(txtQta);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the text box's `TextMode` property to `TextBoxMode.Number`:

```
txtQty.TextMode = TextBoxMode.Number;
```

See [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.textmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for details.

Note: that enum value is only available since .NET 4.5. And since it makes use of a HTML 5 feature, it might not work in all (older) browsers.